# Schema for pyarrow.ParquetDataset > partition columns

Tags: python, pandas, hive, parquet, pyarrow

1. I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3.0, 4.0], "col3": ["foo", "bar"]})
```

2. Using [s3fs](https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs):

```
from s3fs import S3FileSystem

s3fs = S3FileSystem(**kwargs)
```

3. I can write this as a parquet dataset

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

tbl = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
root_path = "../parquet_dataset/foo"

pq.write_to_dataset(
    table=tbl,
    root_path=root_path,
    filesystem=s3fs,
    partition_cols=["col3"],
    partition_filename_cb=lambda _: "data.parquet",
)
```

5. Later, I need the `pq.ParquetSchema` for the dumped DataFrame.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(root_path, filesystem=s3fs)
schema = dataset.schema
```

However parquet dataset -> "schema" does not include partition cols schema.

How do I get the schema for the partition columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to explicitly dump "metadata".

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(
    table=table,
    root_path=path,
    filesystem=s3fs,
    partition_cols=partition_cols,
    partition_filename_cb=lambda _: "data.parquet",
)

# Write metadata-only Parquet file from schema
pq.write_metadata(
    schema=table.schema, where=path + "/_common_metadata", filesystem=s3fs
)
```

Docs https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#writing-metadata-and-common-medata-files

I only care about the "common metadata" but you can dump row stats.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need give `ParquetDataset` a hint of the partition keys schema.

```
partition_schema = pa.schema([pa.field('col3', pa.string())])
partitioning = pa.dataset.partitioning(schema=partition_schema)

partitionaldataset = pq.ParquetDataset(
    root_path, 
    partitioning=partitioning,
)
```

Which gives you this schema:

```
col1: int64
col2: double
col3: string
```

PS: I couldn't completely reproduce your example (I don't have access to S3) and I had to add `use_legacy_dataset=False` when writing and reading the dataset.

Comment: When Im loading parquet dataset from disk/s3 I dont know the schema for any of the columns and hence me trying to get the schema from the file.

Comment: I don't `write_to_dataset` stores any meta data information about the partitioning. So you have to either store it manually when writing the dataset, or remember it when you read it.